# Paytm Integration in React native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-paytm npm package but I am getting 404 not found error while calling paytm.startPayment(details) method.

```
runTransaction(checkSum) {

      const details = {
          mode: "Staging", // 'Staging' or 'Production'
          mid: "CRmldF93384691886347",
          industryType: "Retail",
          website: "APPSTAGING",
          channel: "WAP",
          amount: "1.00", // String
          orderId: "ORDERJEE00001", // String
          email: "abc@gmail.com", // String
          phone: "7777777777", // String
          custId: "CUST0001", // String
          checksumhash: checkSum, //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility 
          callback: "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction?ORDER_ID=ORDERJEE00001&MID=CRmldF93384691886347",
      };

      try{
        paytm.startPayment(details);
      }
      catch(e){
        Alert.alert(e)
      }

  }
```

Comment: did you get the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [@philly25/react-native-paytm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@philly25/react-native-paytm)

It uses latest SDK and also supports latest React Native.